# how to get an vertical histogram of an binary image and based on that histogram segment words from a row

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram, image-segmentation

suppose i have an image in which there are some letters.based on those letters of the image i want to show the vertical projections of histogram  of  the given image in an axes:
[image]

i tried `imhist('image')`but its not showing the projection its only giving a white box on my GUI axes

```
a=imhist(Iedge2);
imshow(a,'Parent',handles.axes2);
title('HISTOGRAM OF DILATED IMAGE')
```

in this `iedge2`is the inverted binary image.

after getting the vertical histogram I want to segment the inverted binary image into vertical segments as the words of sentence/ letters of the word, where there are less or no white pixels 
I am not getting how to do please help
**sir after applying your code i am getting the following output**

[image]
i have combined the screenshots in a single snapshot so that will be easy to u to see in a single image of outputs

Comment: turn the second image 90 degrees clockwise. put some more effort into your question. one has to guess what you want. read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are **not** looking for a  "vertical histogram", but rather a *bar plot* of vertical sum.

Here's a simplified example.

Consider this input image
[image]

You can read and threshold it

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YonG.png')
bw = img(:,:,1)<128;  %// convert to binary, text = 1
```

Now you can inspect the vertical sum

```
sc = sum(bw,1);  %// sum columns
figure;bar(sc);
```

[image]

As you can see if there are more than ~2 pixels set in a column - this is probably a letter. We can use this threshold

```
rm = sc > 2; 
cs = cumsum(~rm).*rm;  %// assign unique value to each "letter" columns
mask = bsxfun(@times, bw, cs );  %// seperate the letters in the mask
```

Resulting with

[image]

Comment: after executing this code  i am  getting these images 1 by one but here i am combined them in a single one

Comment: i am unable to add image in comment

Comment: @ayushibhatnagar you may edit your question to add images

Comment: @ayushibhatnagar it's not "sir", it's "your royal highness" ;)

Comment: How to do this using python instead of matlab?

Comment: @parth.singh71 `sc = bw.sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code i was looking for my question**

```
 clear all;
cd('C:\Users\IFIM\Desktop\New folder\KANND_HAND_SET');
myFolder = 'C:\Users\IFIM\Desktop\segment';
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.bmp','Select image to be read.');
i= imread(fullfile(pathname,filename));
i=padarray(i,[0 10]);
verticalProjection = sum(i, 1);
set(gcf, 'Name', 'DEMO BY SOUMYADEEP', 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
subplot(2, 2, 1);imshow(i); 
subplot(2,2,3);
plot(verticalProjection, 'b-');
grid on;
t = verticalProjection;
t(t==0) = inf;
mayukh=min(t)
% 0 where there is background, 1 where there are letters
letterLocations = verticalProjection > mayukh; 
% Find Rising and falling edges
d = diff(letterLocations);
startingColumns = find(d>0);
endingColumns = find(d<0);
% Extract each region
y=1;
for k = 1 : length(startingColumns)
  % Get sub image of just one character...
  subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k)); 
[L,num] = bwlabel(subImage);
for z= 1 : num
bw= ismember( L, z);
% Construct filename for this particular image.
baseFileName = sprintf('curvedimage %d.png', y);
 y=y+1;
% Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
% Do the write to disk.
imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
subplot(2,2,4);
pause(2);
imshow(bw);
end;
y=y+1;
end;
```